# Python finding stdin filepath on Linux

Tags: python, stdin, filepath

How can I tell the file (or tty) that is attached to my stdios?

Something like:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdin.__path__
'/dev/tty1'
>>>
```

I could look in proc:

```
import os, sys
os.readlink('/proc/self/fd/%s' % sys.stdin.fileno())
```

But seems like there should be a builtin way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> print os.ttyname(sys.stdin.fileno())
'/dev/pts/0'
>>>
```

It `raise`s `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` if stdin isn't a TTY; but thats easy enough to test for with `isatty()`

Answer (score 2):

The sys.std* objects are [standard Python file objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), so they have a [`name` attribute](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.name) and a [`isatty` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.isatty):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.name
'<stdout>'
>>> sys.stdout.isatty()
True
>>> anotherfile = open('/etc/hosts', 'r')
>>> anotherfile.name
'/etc/hosts'
>>> anotherfile.isatty()
False
```

Short of telling you exactly what TTY device you got, that's the extend of the API offered by Python.

Comment: Keep in mind that `stdout` et. al. may be a file-like object that doesn't have `name` and/or `isatty()`, so you should be prepared for that to happen.

Comment: I was hoping to find out what TTY device i was attached to (if stdios are attached to a TTY)

Comment: @kindall: Of course; for stdout all that is required is a `write` method.
@tMC: then all you can do is check the '/proc' filesystem, or if the OS provides such info via a library, use ctypes to access that info. There is no further stdlib python API for this, AFAIC.